# NodeJS/Sequelize/MySQL - Why postgres dependencies are needed?

Tags: mysql, node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

I'm new to Node and Sequelize and I'm facing a problem with establishing connection to MySQL database. I wonder why Postgres dependencies are needed even if set the dialect to mysql one. I would be grateful if you can help me to point the problem.

From **packages.json**

```
"dependencies": {
    // ...
    "mysql2": "1.1.2",
    "sequelize": "3.27.0"
},
```

The way I'm trying to connect db:

```
var Sequelize = require('sequelize');

var sequelize = new Sequelize('dbName', 'dbUser', 'dbPass', {
    host: 'localhost',
    dialect: 'mysql'
});

sequelize.authenticate()
    .then(function(err) {
        console.log('Connection has been established successfully.');
    })
    .catch(function (err) {
        console.log('Unable to connect to the database:', err);
    });
```

The error I'm facing:

```
Failed to compile.

Error in ./~/sequelize/lib/dialects/postgres/hstore.js
Module not found: 'pg-hstore' in ~/node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/postgres
@ ./~/sequelize/lib/dialects/postgres/hstore.js 3:13-33
```

---

**UPDATE 1** (`sequelize init` command used)

From **models/index.js**:

```
'use strict';

var fs        = require('fs');
var path      = require('path');
var Sequelize = require('sequelize');
var basename  = path.basename(module.filename);
var env       = 'development'; //process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development';
var config    = require(__dirname + '/../config/config.json')[env];
var db        = {};

if (config.use_env_variable) {
  var sequelize = new Sequelize(process.env[config.use_env_variable]);
} else {
  var sequelize = new Sequelize(config.database, config.username, config.password, config);
}

fs
  .readdirSync(__dirname)
  .filter(function(file) {
    return (file.indexOf('.') !== 0) && (file !== basename) && (file.slice(-3) === '.js');
  })
  .forEach(function(file) {
    var model = sequelize['import'](path.join(__dirname, file));
    db[model.name] = model;
  });

Object.keys(db).forEach(function(modelName) {
  if (db[modelName].associate) {
    db[modelName].associate(db);
  }
});

db.sequelize = sequelize;
db.Sequelize = Sequelize;

module.exports = db;
```

And my **config/config.json**:

```
{
  "development": {
    "username": "dbUser",
    "password": "dbPassword",
    "database": "dbName",
    "host": "127.0.0.1",
    "dialect": "mysql2"
  },
  "test": {
    "username": "root",
    "password": null,
    "database": "database_test",
    "host": "127.0.0.1",
    "dialect": "mysql2"
  },
  "production": {
    "username": "root",
    "password": null,
    "database": "database_production",
    "host": "127.0.0.1",
    "dialect": "mysql2"
  }
}
```

---

**UPDATE 2**

Now I see I have an additional message:

```
Error: The dialect mysql is not supported. (Error: Cannot find module './mysql'.)
```

However, I have it installed in to root of the `node_modules` directory.

---

**UPDATE 3**

The steps I take to reproduce the problem:

- `create-react-app tmpApp`
- `npm install --save mysql sequelize`
- `npm install -g sequelize-cli`
- `sequelize init`
- add to `src/index.js`: `var models = require('../models')`
- `npm start` - the problem appears

---

**UPDATE 4 - Problem resolved**

First of all really thanks for your help! The problem actually occurred because I was trying to mix server and client sides into one application (I was just playing). The Sequelize and the mysql modules itself do not seem to work on the browser environment. When the server side is placed outside the react-app everything behaves as expected.

Comment: You shouldn't need the postgres module. Make sure that you're using the `mysql2` dialect though and not `mysql` since you're using the `mysql2` interface.

Comment: what is the value you get when you do `console.log(config)` in `models/index.js`

Comment: @AJS, the `config.use_env_variable` is undefined, what seems to be reasonable to me, since I don't want to use configuration taken from environmental variable but from the `config.json`. Am I right?

Comment: yes it is what about config variable what is its output

Comment: I've updated my question

Answer (score 1):

In your database config, you must have set the config as something else to be used.

1. Check the env using sequelize. Usually, it's a config.json file inside your database directory.
2. Change the dialect to mysql2 since that's what you want to use.

Comment: My project was pretty empty, so I've just used sequelize-cli init command and than modified `config/config.json`. Now I also use the sequelize instance from `models/index.js`, but the problem remains. Dialect of course changed to `mysql2`.

Comment: Show your `models/index.js` It should by default use the development config from `config.json` Otherwise it's defaulted to use postgres.

Comment: @Anirudha if you change to dialect `mysql2` it willl give you following error:  **Supported dialects: mariadb, mssql, mysql, postgres, and sqlite.**

Comment: @Mat You need to install these dependencies. `npm install --save mysql`

Comment: @Anirudha, actually I have it. In fact I've found the problem - please take a look at my updated question.

Comment: Cool. Should have started with directory listings. :)

Answer (score -1):

To solve your problem do:

```
`npm install mysql ---save` instead of `mysql2`
```

that will get your code working. And from what i saw in offical docs [here](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/docs/getting-started/) they seem to support mysql2 as well but it doesn't work. As i have tested and got similar results. I will suggest raise a issue in their github so they can fix it their. You can do so [here](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues)

Comment: Unfortunately, I've already tried both of them with the same result:
`Error: The dialect mysql is not supported. (Error: Cannot find module './mysql'.)`.

or

`Error: The dialect mysql2 is not supported. (Error: Cannot find module './mysql2'.)`

 Of course I have them installed.

Comment: it worked when i tried it why not remove both and just install `mysql` again, you can do so by `npm uninstall <module_name> --save`

Comment: keep dialect as `mysql` not `mysql2`

Comment: Dialect set to `mysql` and npm packages: `"mysql": "2.12.0"`, `"sequelize": "2.0.0"`. The problem remains though.

Comment: is your code exactly shown in your post? ie. file where you are creating connection?

Comment: sequlize version was 3.27 in your post, how is it 2.0.0 now?

Comment: Right. I was just playing with the sequelize version, but  with no positive results. The 3.27 version does not change anything in the case of my problem. It just can't find the mysql module. I've read that it may occur when it is not placed in the root on node_modules, but it is.